# GoogleMapView showing only one marker even its has 2 or more

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to figure it out why my google map view only show one marker on the screen even the fetch data got 2 records.I use realm to store latitude and longitude of each position.Even my realm has two markers position,why it drop only one marker,Any help?

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
var locationMarker: GMSMarker!
var locationList : Results<TowerLocationList>!

@IBAction func findAddress(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Clearing all marker to protect duplicate marker drop
    self.mapView.clear()

    //Fetching all marker from realm object
    locationList = realm.objects(TowerLocationList)

    print("The list included at Realm DB is : \(locationList)")

    print("List count : \(locationList.count)")

    for var i = 0 ; i < locationList.count; i++ {
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(locationList[i].latitude)!, longitude: Double(locationList[i].longitude)!)
        self.setupLocationMarker(coordinate)
        print("For Loop i : \(i)")
    }
}

func setupLocationMarker(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {


    locationMarker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
    locationMarker.map = mapView

    locationMarker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
    locationMarker.icon = UIImage(named: "Radio_Tower")
    //locationMarker.opacity = 0.75

    locationMarker.flat = true

    locationList = realm.objects(TowerLocationList).filter("longitude = '\(coordinate.longitude)' AND latitude = '\(coordinate.latitude)'")
    locationMarker.snippet = locationList[0].siteCode

    print(locationMarker.snippet)

}
```

When I click findAddress button,
The Output is :

```
The list included at Realm DB is : Results<TowerLocationList> (
[0] TowerLocationList {
    siteCode = AY0121;
    longitude = 96.1265519633889;
    latitude = 16.8548376155088;
},
[1] TowerLocationList {
    siteCode = AY0119;
    longitude = 96.1268738284707;
    latitude = 16.8490258657804;
}
)
List count : 2
Optional("AY0121")
For Loop i : 0
```

why the loop stop at index 0 and doesn't go to index 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting this up inside your method for `setupLocationMarker(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D)` this is where you will need to place all of your individual markers.

```
mapView.clear()
for spot in locationList {
    let marker = GMSMarker(place: spot)
    marker.map = self.mapView
    marker.snippet = spot.title 
    //etc
}
```

Comment: I tried it,it still didn't work out. Here : http://puu.sh/nzXZK/2a50a5a6e8.png . Only show one marker,whats wrong with me?;(

Comment: I got it now : http://puu.sh/nzYiv/59cfe753fa.png. May i know what's the difference?

Comment: Mind explain me?why it drop only one marker at normal for loop instead of for each loop?